# Batch how to set FINDSTR result to a variable and disable findstr print to console

Tags: batch-file

My batch program

```
FINDSTR  /C:"Result Comparison failure"  %tmp_result_file%
```

I want to do the folloiwng , set the result of the above command to a variable. 
If found, set the first line to varible or set the all found line to a varible is OK for me.

also the above commmand will print the findstr command to console even @echo off. is there any method to disable the print.

thanks a lot

---

part of my script, what i do is run command on every line in sourcefile and put the run result into a tmp file, then use find str to find the failed string to check the run result.

```
for /f  %%a in (%source_file%) do (
    echo  run %%a >> %output_file%
    call  %run_script_command% %%a > %tmp_result_file% 2>&1
    ::notepad %tmp_result_file%
      for /f %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"Result Comparison failure"  %tmp_result_file%') do  echo %%ixxx
    echo xx
)
```

very strange , the result is:

```
    xx
    Resultxxx
    xx
```

the background is that i have two items in `%source_file%`, so the out for run 2 times.
for the first one, the FINDSTR can not find anything, so print `xxx`
for the second one, it find one in findstr , but only print "`Result`" instead of "`Result Comparison failure`", also the xx is print before it in result. Very Strange!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first problem is because you just take the first token from FOR. To solve it, you have two solutions, either to echo the complete line where the string is found...

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"Result Comparison Failure" %tmp_result_file%') do echo %%i
```

or echo the three tokens found

```
for /f %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"Result Comparison Failure" %tmp_result_file%') do echo %%i %%j %%k
```

the second problem, the xx echoed two times is because you run two times the command. The first xx is the one from the first run, the second one is from the second run. If you want to prevent the second one, you need to use some additional logic. For example, setting a variable and then checking it. Warning, setting a variable in a loop requires enabling delayed expansion and using the !xx! syntax (see HELP SET for a detailed explanation)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
...
set result=
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"Result Comparison Failure" %tmp_result_file%') do (
  set result=%%i
)
if "!result!"=="" ( 
  echo !result!
) else (
  echo xx
)
```

Comment: +1, but why not compare the value of `%%i` directly? Like this (in the inner loop's body): `IF "%%i" == "" (ECHO xx) ELSE ECHO %%i`.

Comment: yep, you're right, that's a possibility.. I just reused code handling multiple find results.

Comment: tokens=* belongs before %%i, doesn't it?

Comment: There is syntax error `"tokens=*" was unexpected at this time.` on the first  given `for /F` command. `"tokens=*"` should be placed before `%%i`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the FOR /F command.

```
for /f %i in ('FINDSTR  /C:"Result Comparison failure"  %tmp_result_file%') do ...
```

Comment: Type `for /?` to see all the options. The delims option seems relevant here. I was trying to point you in the right direction, not to solve your entire problem for you.

Comment: You probably want `for /f "delims=" %%i in (...`

Comment: @RaymondChen Then how would expect to get the check mark for the _Answer_?

Comment: @Jamie The answer is to use FOR /F. The question as originally posed was so broad that it was basically a "write by program for me" which SO is not intended to be.

Comment: @RaymondChen Fair enough, the question as I see it lacks the context I expect you originally had.