# Batch Test if result of a findstr command is empty

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch which search a line in a text file and return true if the line is found or false if it's not.

This how I finf the line, but I don't know how to test it:

```
findstr /r /c:"^Process Status.*no errors, no warnings$" myfile.log
```

Can you help me on this please?

Thanks

Comment: This question was already answered in a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605328/batch-how-to-set-findstr-result-to-a-variable-and-disable-findstr-print-to-conso?rq=1

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
findstr /r /c:"^Process Status.*no errors, no warnings$" myfile.log > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo The line was not found
) else (
    echo The line was found
)
```

Check if the command sets errorlevel. If it is set, the text was not found.